# Add Author Username @bot.event

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I add Author Username at `@bot.event` function?

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
    username = ctx.author.name
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{username}",description="Logs Server", color=discord.Color.purple(), timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    channel=bot.get_channel(id)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I think I understand what you mean.

Because you're working inside of **on_message_edit**, the *message_before* and *message_after* are both `discord.Message` objects. You could try something like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
    username = str(message_after.author)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=username,description="Logs Server", color=discord.Color.purple(), timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    channel = bot.get_channel(id)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The **ctx** you had originally ("username = ctx.author.name") will not be defined. This is because we usually only have context from inside of a command, which this is not.